# Create view in MySQL ndbcluster engine

Tags: mysql

I have installed and configured **MySQL(ndbcluster engine)** in two machines. Such as ip of those machines are xxx.xxx.xxx.1 and xxx.xxx.xxx.2.

I have created a db and some tables. I have created the tables only in one machine(xxx.xxx.xxx.1) with mentioning engine as ndbcluster. So I can see the tables in both machine(also in xxx.xxx.xxx.2).

But while I create a view in one machine. It doesn't show in the other machine!
What should I do to see the view in both machine by creating once in one machine.

Isn't it possible?

Or, do I need to create the view in both machine?

Another question: Can I create a view in mysql specifying the db engine(i.e: innodb, ndbcluster)?

N.B: My MySQL is server is configured as ndbcluster.